# How to use a pre trained model on Image net in tensorflow object detection api

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I am trying to use the Inception SSD model in tensorflow object detection API. To initialize the weights i want to use pretrained Inception V2 On image net as the feature extractor. I see the model config file lets you use a pretrained model on COCO but if I want to use an Image net model how should I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

To train on Imagenet classification models, do the following:

1) Download a pre-trained model from the "Pre-trained models" section on the [Slim page](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/slim)
2) Point the `fine_tune_checkpoint` at that directory
3) Set `from_detection_checkpoint` to be false (as you will now be fine-tuning from a classification checkpoint)

Note that training from an Imagenet classification checkpoint will require  significantly more time.